How can I prevent solid mix-ins from sinking or floating in my sous vide egg bites
Inspired by https://recipes.anovaculinary.com/recipe/sous-vide-egg-bites-bacon-gruyere I tried to make a variant of this recipe. My primary goal was to cook a single "log" of egg bites which I could then slice into rounds after cooking.
Recipe/Procedure: I blended together:

6 eggs
3/4 cups cheese
assorted dried herbs

Then I stirred in:

4 thin rashers of cooked bacon (cut into tiny 1/4 inch squares)

This mixture was then sealed into a plastic tube and cooked sous vide at 172°F for 1 hour. In the water bath the tube was (roughly) horizontal and submerged the whole time.
Problem: The resulting texture and flavor were pleasing, however almost all the bacon "sunk" to the bottom and almost all of the dried herbs "floated" to the top.
Question: How can I adjust my procedure or recipe to keep a more even distribution of my "solid mix-ins"?



I can only think of two ways to accomplish this:

Use a thickener or gel to make the mixture set or at least hold things in place before you cook it. I don't like this idea much as thickening so much it sets at room temperature is likely going to have an unpleasant texture when cooked. However, I could be wrong (believe it or not it has happened once or twice), so it could be worth a shot. I'd use Arrowroot powder for this, maybe potato starch.
Keep rolling the tubes in the sous vide machine until the eggs sets. Eggs set between about 145°F and 160°F, or 62°C - 71°C, so it's not going to happen immediately. I'd first try rolling the tubes 180 degrees and maybe giving them a little shake ever 5-10 minutes


Thank you for the ideas. I agree that (1) feels like it has promise but may compromise on texture -- probably still worth experimenting with though. Your idea for (2) gives me ideas though. I wonder what if I: (a) initially set the water bath to some lower temp [145-160 maybe?] (b) wait some time for temperature equilibrium and eggs to partially thicken (c) shake to redistribute solid mix-ins (d) raise water bath temp to desired final cooking temp and finish cooking.

I wouldn't bother with a two stage process, all you need is to get the timing right.

Idea 2 is crying out for mechanisation, like a Lego (should just about take the heat) version of a hotdog machine.  A long rubber band drive would keep the motor out of the water
